# Should I use struct or array to represent x, y, and z coordinates?

Tags: performance, data-structures, coding-style, standards

What is the difference between using an array to store in x, y, and z versus using an object (struct) that has x, y, and z coordinates as variables when it comes to readability, speed, memory, and so on.

Any information is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a `struct` like in C, it's stored the same way as an array in memory.  In fact, if your `struct` had only `int` fields for instance, you could cast a pointer to that `struct` to an `int` pointer and see it behaves the same as an `int` array.  I would not recommend that though, just an observation.

I don't see a benefit of using one over the other, just do what's easiest for you.  I would prefer the `struct` however since the field names are more descriptive than array indices.